# A PDF with link to specific page goes to the wrong page when viewing the PDF in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

I created a PDF manual that has a table of contents that links to specific pages. I add some of the links through Adobe Acrobat because I have to add pages after the PDF is created and cannot make the links in InDesign.

The links work correctly when viewing in Adobe Reader, Safari, Mac Preview, Firefox, Ect. but doesn't work when the PDF is viewed in Chrome. I am using Chrome Version 105.0.5195.125. In the below gifs, the link should go to page 98.

**When viewing in Adobe Reader**

[image: reader]

**When viewing in Chrome**

[image: chrome]

Comment: I do not have an answer, but this is one of the anomalies of PDF files. I see this reasonably frequently

Answer (score 0):

While Chrome PDF viewer is probably the best PDF reader for viewing documents fast and instantly in your browser, it has limited options and tools. In fact, the only thing you can do is zoom in and out and print.

Otherwise, for more professional secure document sharing, file sharing and document management solutions that offer more than what Chrome PDF viewer provides, you have many options out there. In this case, I personally recommend you using a third-party PDF software such as [SwifDoo PDF](https://www.swifdoo.com/).